# dynamically accessing column from a dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with several columns. var1, var2, target1, target2, target3, etc.
I can to df.target1.plot()

I was wondering how to do this dynamically.
I want to write a function

```
def f(target)
```

where target is a string.
Within this function, I want to be able to do df.target.plot()
Essentially, the function should be able to achieve

```
def f(target):
    df.target.plot()
```

But i'm not sure how to do it since target is a string.

Comment: `df[target].plot()`

Comment: See also: [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](/q/2612610/4518341). Although the indexing syntax is recommended for Pandas; the attribute syntax is only provided as a convenience.

Comment: You might want to do a Pandas tutorial. This is covered in [10 minutes to pandas § Selection](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html#selection).